# Converting integer to float datatype in string

Tags: java, regex, types

I'm using Beanshell interpreter to evaluate simple math expressions like

```
5*3*(2+4)/2.2
```

the problem is to convert for example the above expressions in Java into

```
5.0*3.0*(2.0+4.0)/2.2
```

This is because I want floating-point result. What regexp can be used to achieve this?

Comment: Regex is **not** the solution.

Comment: If you start to handle numbers as text you are doing something wrong.

Comment: math expression as a text is an input to my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<!\d\.)(\d+)(?!\.)
```

Try this .Replace by

`$1.0`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/24

Comment: What about `2*3*4*5*(6+7+3)/(2.6+8)`?

Comment: did you check your code with this `95*3*(2+4)/2.2` ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun it is wrokign fine.

Comment: I've corrected a bit the regex you have provided like this 
`(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)(\d+)(?!\.)(?!\d)` so now it can correctly process input like `5*5.434*333.43*443.43`